# findall error - NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I keep getting the error "missing 1 required positional argument: 'section_url'"

Every time I try working with findall I get this error.

New to learning python so any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3


def extract_data():

    BASE_URL = "http://www.chicagotribune.com/dining/ct-chicago-rooftops-patios-eat-drink-outdoors-near-me-story.html"

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'http://www.chicagotribune.com/dining/ct-chicago-rooftops-patios-eat-drink-outdoors-near-me-story.html')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.data, 'html.parser')
    heading = soup.find("div", "strong")
    category_links = [BASE_URL + p.a['href'] for p in heading.findAll('p')]
    return category_links
    print(soup)


extract_data()
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on Accepted Answer's answer, I think this is what you want

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib3

def extract_data():

    BASE_URL = "http://www.chicagotribune.com/dining/ct-chicago-rooftops-patios-eat-drink-outdoors-near-me-story.html"

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    r = http.request('GET', 'http://www.chicagotribune.com/dining/ct-chicago-rooftops-patios-eat-drink-outdoors-near-me-story.html')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.data, 'html.parser')
    heading = soup.select('div strong')
    print(heading)
    category_links = [BASE_URL + p.a['href'] for p in [i for i, x in enumerate(heading) if x == "p"]]
    return category_links


print(extract_data())
```

Comment: If it's not then do share what you expect the output of `extract_data()` to be.

Comment: Thank you thank you! Exactly what I want. I so appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, `NoneType object has no attribute` class of errors means that the upstream function returned `None`, then you did not check for it and tried to access its methods:

```
stuff = get_stuff()  # this returns None
stuff.do_stuff()  # this crashes
```

Most likely, the library could not find the heading with `soup.find`. Try to use `soup.select('div.strong')` instead.

More on selectors:
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors

More on NoneType:
https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/constants.html#None

Comment: Thank you so much for responding! I tried that, but still same error unfortunately. Every time I have tried using findAll I get this error.